# Android: Animation does not work for specified duration

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I am trying to do animation with my custom view. This custom view is a combination of other view. I am trying to do a very simple animation and it get triggered when a button is clicked. I want the view to slide and disappear in 2 seconds. But It seems it disappears in less than 2 seconds. I tried to increase the duration but it did not help.

```
public void hideBar() {
        this.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

 private void animateAndHide(){

        this.animate()
            .translationY(0)
            .setDuration(2000)
            .alpha(0.0f)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    hideBar();
                }
            });
    }
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Better to create xml of animation, and define your duration there :)

Comment: did you measure the animation time or is it just your impression?

Comment: @JhamanDas I am not sure how to define the xml animation. I would appreciate any reference.

Comment: @pskink I don't know how to measure the time. But tried the increasing the value of duration and I don't notice any change in animation.

Comment: call `System#currentTimeMillis` in both `onAnimationStart` and `onAnimationEnd`

Comment: @pskink I tried and I get 22 milliseconds which is way below than expected value (2000)

Comment: so you have animations disabled in dev opts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109385/discussion-between-rakesh-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me before the view seems to be invisible because the alpha becomes very low before it becomes 0 so try another value like alpha 0.1

Comment: I tried with different alpha value but I didn't see any improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `setStartOffset(2000)`? The offset will delay your animation, so if you want to start your animation after a specific time, use the offset method.

Comment: I don't see any `setStartOffset()` method so I tried with `setStartDelay()` method. It doesn't improve anything result is the same.